# jQuery Function and Javascript Functions Not Working Together

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, colorbox

I am trying to run a jQuery function with some other Javascript functions. I suppose I am not understanding the syntax correctly. I have a colorbox that opens on page load with a form in it. When the form is submitted I am trying to have a validation run first and then if successful run a jQuery function that closes the Colorbox and validates the parent window. This is where I'm at now (by the way, I've been all around the circle with this. I've been able to get the jQuery function to work, I've gotten the validation functions to work but I've never gotten them to work together. I apologize if I've gotten way off base but I think I've drifted away since I was trying some new things):

Just tried this:

```
window.echeck(str) = function {

    var at="@"
    var dot="."
    var lat=str.indexOf(at)
    var lstr=str.length
    var ldot=str.indexOf(dot)
    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1){
       alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
       return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1 || str.indexOf(at)==0 || str.indexOf(at)==lstr){
       alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
       return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(dot)==-1 || str.indexOf(dot)==0 || str.indexOf(dot)==lstr){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
    }

     if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
        alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
        return false
     }

     return true                    
}

window.ValidateForm() = function{
var emailID=document.MailingList.emailaddress

if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value=="")){
    alert("Please Enter your Email ID")
    emailID.focus()
    return false
}
if (echeck(emailID.value)==false){
    emailID.value=""
    emailID.focus()
    return false
}
return true
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#submitbutton').live('click', function(e) {     
        ValidateForm();
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); 
        parent.location.href = "/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1854";
    });
});
```

I didn't execute any of the functions.

When I remove ValidateForm(); from the jQuery and when I put the syntax of the javascript functions back to `function ValidateForm();` instead of `window.ValidateForm = function()` the jQuery works but of course the other javascript functions do not.

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but your email validation test condition `str.indexOf(at)==lstr` isn't doing what you think because `lstr` is `str.length` and the length of the string is one more than the index of the last character (because the indexes are zero-based). If you're trying to test the last character you need `str.indexOf(at)==lstr-1`. But I'd suggest you replace the half-dozen `if` statements that test the email format with a one-line regex `.test()`.

Answer (score 1):

> an I not create nested functions inside of the main jQuery function

You can't reference functions from outside the `$(document).ready(function() { });` block, because it's a private scope.  You need to either define one of the functions outside of the scope, so that it's accessible --

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // define in the global scope (window) so that it's accessible anywhere
    window.ValidateForm = function() { ... }
});

// this works
ValidateForm();
```

or wire up your events by using `on` --

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theform").on("submit", ValidateForm);
});
```

Comment: _"because it is a closure."_ - You're mixing up "closure" and "scope".

Comment: @nnnnnn hm, I guess I am.  Hopefully that is better.

Comment: If I defined the function outside of the scope (I kind of understand that better than the other one), would I then just have to call it like a normal function i.e. ValidateForm(); if I was to use your above example?

Comment: @MxmastaMills yes, exactly -- if you use `window.ValidateForm` then you can call it normally from anywhere in the document.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try that. I just broke the code but put an edit up top asking if I've got the idea right...I just want to make sure I'm on the right track. Thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: Alright one more thing, when I changed the functions to window.ValidateForm, etc. it caused the jQuery to stop working (even if I didn't call the function inside the jQuery). When I went back to the original syntax, the jQuery worked again...

Comment: @MxmastaMills I see you've added another section `$('#submitbutton').live('click', function(e) {  })` ... if you already had this, then it probably means what I wrote in my answer doesn't matter, you already had that part right.  Can you please remove the edit, and just post your original code including the `live` event wireup section?

Comment: Yeah I'll go back and edit. I just revert back to the original (the stuff I posted here was after a while of edits). I'll do that now. Thanks.

Comment: Alright edits done. This is back to my code from a while ago. Thanks.